# Cannot lock Build Output Cleanup Cache

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I am having issues with my flutter project. Whenever I run the flutter build apk command. I get the following error message. I tried flutter clean but it does not solve the problem. Here is my error message.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not create service of type OutputFilesRepository using ExecutionGradleServices.createOutputFilesRepository().
         > Cannot lock Build Output Cleanup Cache (C:\Users\JUSTINE NALWOGA\Desktop\EDUSELF FINAL\eduself\android\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup) as it has already been locked by this process.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 22s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          337.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 16):

Try running this command in a terminal,

```
find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete
```

or

Go to `/.gradle` folder and manually delete all files ending with `.lock`.

Then run `flutter clean`,

`flutter pub get` and finally run

`flutter build apk`.

Comment: I get this, when I run that command in terminal in project folder: `FIND: Parameter format not correct`